How to fold the corner of paper in div?
I need to do a fold corner of the paper in div.
I've read many websites but I'm still confuse how to do it . .
what i got

this is my code
<div style="max-width: 700px; height: auto; background-color: #fff;">
<div style="max-width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: transparent; border-width: 0 20px 20px 0; border-style: solid; border-color: #A6A49D #fff;">
</div></div>

what i need


Using a image or svg would be lot better.

You may looking something like this. Modify according to your needs if necessary.


.card {
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #8C46C8;
  position: relative;
  &::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px 0px 70px 70px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
    
    border-top-color: #521A80;
    border-bottom-color: #521A80;
  }
}
<div class='card'></div>




i found this for your problem:
.page-flip {
    height: 400px;
  padding: 25px 25px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 90%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #999; 
  background: #fff;
  transition: all ease .5s;
  border:5px solid #999;
}
.page-flip:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 100px 100px 0;
  border-color: #ddd black;
  transition: all ease .5s;
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
